Meaning of some lines in echo.c in coreutils project
I am reading the source code of echo.c of coreutils project.
I can't understand the meaning of the following:

At line 79 (and some other lines), the meaning of _ function in fputs (_("\nIf -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:\n\n"), stdout);

At line 116, the meaning of !! in bool posixly_correct = !!getenv ("POSIXLY_CORRECT");




In system.h there is #define _(msgid) gettext (msgid)


Please only ask one question at a time. Question 2 is answered in previous questions, so I've closed this entire question as a duplicate.


The _ is a shorthand macro defined by gettext for translations. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Overview .

! is a logical not operator. The !! is one of the ways to convert anything to 1 or 0, in this case a non-NULL or NULL value is converted to 1 or 0 (true or false) respectively.

nowadays bool is special, so just bool posixly_correct = getenv ("POSIXLY_CORRECT"); woudl suffice and the right side would be implicitly converted to 1 or 0 when assinging to bool. But some days ago bool did not exists, it was emulated with #define bool int or similar, in which case !! might have had some meaning.




The ! is a NOT. The !! is NOT NOT.
!!getenv ("POSIXLY_CORRECT") is being used as a shorthand for getenv ("POSIXLY_CORRECT") != NULL.
